# How to stack elements of a list (dataframes or vectors) by rows inside a matrix, including the names of the columns in R?

Tags: r, list, data-wrangling

My goal is to export several dataframes to a single Excel sheet.

I want a general code that works with any list.

**Outline of the data**

```r
# df1
  a
1 1
2 1

# df2
  b c
1 3 4

# vec
[1] "string"
```

**Desired output**

```r
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] "a"      NA  
[2,] "1"      NA  
[3,] "1"      NA  
[4,] NA       NA  
[5,] "b"      "c" 
[6,] "3"      "4" 
[7,] NA       NA  
[8,] "string" NA
```

**Data**

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(b = 3, c = 4)
vec <- "string"
l   <- list(df1, df2, vec)
```

Comment: I want  a space between elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you need to export to a single Excel sheet. You can use `{openxlsx}` with a simple loop to calculate the starting row in the excel sheet for each element in the list.

```r
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")
sr <- 1 # startRow

for(x in lst) {
  writeData(wb, "sheet1", x, startRow = sr, colNames = !is.null(colnames(x)))
  sr <- sr + ifelse(!is.null(nrow(x)), nrow(x) + !is.null(colnames(x)), length(x)) + 1L
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

- Figure: `test.xlsx`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add the names of the elements of the list just above each matrix (if such a name exist)?